# compare two string in perl to find mismatches

Tags: perl

I am a beginner in Perl. I have a file two column. I want to compare first column (as reference) with second column (test):

```
pppqqrrsttqrstrr    pppqrrrsttqrstrr

if p in ref =~ p in test print p
if q in ref =~ q in test print q
if r in ref =~ r in test print r
if s in ref =~ s in test print s

if t in ref =~ t in test print W

if q in ref =~ r in test print w
```

so output : `pppqwrrsWWqrsWrr`

I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $F1, '>', 'match' or die $!;
while(<>){
    chomp($_);
    my @file = split ("\t| ",$_);
    my @ref = split (//, $file[0]);
    my @test = split (//, $file[1]);
       for my $i (0 .. @ref -1) {
          if(($ref[$i] =~ /Pp/) && ($test[$i] =~ /Pp/)){
            print $F1 ("$ref[$i]");
                     }  
          elsif(($ref[$i] =~ /Qq/) && ($test[$i] =~ /Qq/)){
            print $F1 ("$ref[$i]");
                     }
          elsif(($ref[$i] =~ /Rr/) && ($test[$i] =~ /Rr/)){
            print $F1 ("$ref[$i]");
                     }          
          elsif(($ref[$i] =~ /Ss/) && ($test[$i] =~ /Ss/)){
            print $F1 ("$ref[$i]");
                     }
          elsif(($ref[$i] =~ /Tt/) && ($test[$i] =~ /Tt/)){
            print $F1 ("W");
                     }
          elsif(($ref[$i] =~ m/Qq/) && ($test[$i] =~ m/Rr/)){
            print $F1 ("w");            
                     }
            $i++;       

}print $F1 ("\n");}
close $F1;
```

but I don't get anything!!!

thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like here:

```
$test[$i] =~ /Pp/
```

that you're trying to find a string with either `P` or `p` in it, but what you're actually doing is finding strings with a `P` followed by a `p`.  What you meant to do is:

```
$test[$i] =~ /[Pp]/
```

where `[Pp]` is a character class that will match against either of those.

However, even better is to use the `i` modifier on the regex to make the test case-insensitive

```
$test[$i] =~ /p/i
```